# Cannot preview in file, Active scheme does not build this file

Tags: swift, swiftui, package, preview

I have been trying to preview a file after downloading StarScream through the Swift Package. Sin ce then, i believe that I correctly imported the package, but I can no longer see a preview or the simulator for my code, and see the error message "active scheme does not build this file" in the error message for the preview. I have tried to delete all the schemes, and auto create one, tried pressing all the buttons on the scheme, etc...

Here is my github repo; https://github.com/maxdalat/Productivity

I am trying to see a preview of my xcode project after installing a swift package.

Comment: I can't see the package on your GitHub repo. and can you please attach a screenshot of your problem?  you can also check any other scheme available or not in your project ...

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this error when the path to my Swift project contained hyphens (ex. ~/Dev/VisionOS-tips-and-tricks/Day001).

Changing the folder name to something without hyphens seemed to fix the issue.